# What is the usage of loading firefox with profile

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

My question may look strange or weak, but can you please let me know what are the real usage of loading firefox with any profile?

1. Load firefox with Plug-in(Can someone explain some real scenario). I never come across this situation.
2. I think to resolve SSL Certificate issues. (Nowadays none of bank or financial sites doesnt show these certificate warnings). Where we use this to firefox with profile?

Can you please let us know if there are any other places(realtime scenarions) we may need firefox with profile?

Answer (score 1):

If we donot define any profile then Selenium Webdriver uses default fresh firefox profile.

But in some scenarios, we have specific requirements for browser. For example..

- we can expect it to have history records
- we may want it to remember passwords
- we may need to utilize some firefox plugins during our webdriver tests
- so on..

All above come under personal profile settings, which can be defined in custom profile in our selenium project.

For more details check: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Between, I will suggest you to join https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ that is forum specifically for SQA related questions. You will have greater chances   of getting answers there.

Answer (score 0):

profiling helps us **update the preferences** within Firefox.
We can do this by instantiating a Firefox Profile object and then update the settings.
We will then need to pass this object into Firefox Driver which will load the profile with your defined settings.

For example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FireFoxProfileExample {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void testExamples(){
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage",
"http://www.google.com");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("100");

}
```

Hope this helps you!!!